# How to share Meteor Backend server with a Web and mobile app

Tags: meteor

I am working on an eCommerce project. I want to use amazing meteorjs for this project. I want to know is it possible to share meteor back end server( collections, methods, authentication) with a web and mobile app not just MongoDB. If its possible Please let me know how we can use the same Meteor backend server for multiple apps.

Comment: You can connect with your native Android app (written in Java) with this library: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP However, note that all client libraries don't offer the perfect integration with templates, direct data binding, etc. that Meteor itself offers for the web.

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor client talks to the server using the simple [DDP](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/livedata/DDP.md) protocol. [DDP clients](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients) have been written for a variety of other platforms, including [Android](https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client) and [iOS](https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP).